# Ansible: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters

Tags: ansible

My goal is to eliminate the Ansible warning produced by `device` variable, listed below. I thought making use of `lookup('ansible.builtin.vars', 'device')` will address the issue, but it is not. Can you please provide some advice how I should correctly address the issue? Thank you.

I have the following playbook:

```
- name: Distribution Setup
  hosts: apollo
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    device: ASMedia
  tasks:
    - name: Set device id
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: lsusb -s 2:2
      changed_when: device_id.stdout.find("{{ device }}") != -1
      register: device_id

    - name: Set attribute
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        attribute: "{{ device_id.stdout | regex_search('ID\\s+(.*)\\s+' + lookup('ansible.builtin.vars', 'device'), '\\1') | join | trim | split(':') }}"

    - name: Print attribute information
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: attribute
      when: attribute is iterable and (attribute | length == 2)
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Distribution Setup] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [apollo]
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: device_id.stdout.find("{{ device }}") !=
-1

TASK [Set device id] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [apollo]

TASK [Set attribute] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [apollo]

TASK [Print attribute information] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [apollo] => {
    "attribute": [
        "174c",
        "55aa"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************
apollo                     : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Edit: Fixed playbook, based on accepted answer:

```
- name: Distribution Setup
  hosts: apollo
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    device: ASMedia
  tasks:
    - name: Set device id
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: lsusb -s 2:2
      changed_when: device_id.stdout.find(device) != -1
      register: device_id

    - name: Set attribute
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        attribute: "{{ device_id.stdout | regex_search('ID\\s+(.*)\\s+' + device, '\\1') | join | trim | split(':') }}"

    - name: Print attribute information
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: attribute
      when: attribute is iterable and (attribute | length == 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters`...

Because conditionals (`when`, `changed_when`, etc) are evaluated in an implicit Jinja template context, you should never use `{{` or `}}` markers in these statements. If you want to refer to a variable, just use the variable name; the string `"{{ device }}"` would look for the literal text `{{ device }}`.

Instead of:

```yaml
changed_when: device_id.stdout.find("{{ device }}") != -1
```

You want:

```yaml
changed_when: device_id.stdout.find(device) != -1
```

Comment: Furthermore, you hardly ever want `{{ device_id.stdout.find("{{ device }}") != -1 }}`, either, you want the same as explained here:  `{{ device_id.stdout.find(device) != -1 }}`, because [_moustaches don’t stack_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names).